# How to know which model property the current $formatters action is running for?

Tags: angularjs

I have a model that has tens of properties with corresponding bound form elements in the view. I also have a custom action/function in the $formatters array. I want to set a breakpoint in the function and let it get hit only for a certain property. Or at least have a way to know which modal property the current action execution is happening for. Assume all the properties have the same value, therefore I can't determine which property it is based on the value alone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome Dev Tools, you can see JS call stack, should be:~

```
-formatter function
-ngModelWatch
-$digest
...
```

Now click on ngModelWatch and in closure section you can see NgModelController, which has enough info (i.e. html element).

P.S. of course, you can modify code to add control information to formatter function...

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see any of those in the call stack but found a closure which had the name of the html element. However I don't know how to set a conditional breakpoint for it. I created another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731565/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-conditional-breakpoint-based-on-a-value-in-a-javascript