# Is there a way to set a conditional breakpoint based on a value in a Javascript Closure in a browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to set a conditional breakpoint based on a value in a Javascript Closure in a browser? There's an html element node in the closure whose 'name' property value changes for every AngularJS $formatters action execution. I would like a breakpoint to get hit only for a certain element.

The code snippet is in AngularJS attribute directive.
The breakpoint is on the originalValue line.

This screen capture shows the Closure in the Call Stack in Chrome Dev Tools. There's a property 'name' (not shown) which has the element's name. 
I am looking for a breakpoint expression like this (Obviously not correct) : `Closure (link).element.0.name == 'customerName'`

[image]

[image]

Comment: i think so - showing your real code might help

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but you can always create a conditional breakpoint (with dev tools open) by just adding `debugger;` inside a conditional like `if(name === x) { debugger; }`

Comment: I added a small code snippet which is in an AngularJS attribute directive . The breakpoint in on the Var originalValue line. I only have access to the value parameter. There's no name property here. I found it in a closure as I explained in the question.